# PHP query all column based on one text value filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a text field filter where its value can query back all the data that has the filter value from all column of a table. For now my existing code can only query from column which is the `users.name` Below is my current code :

```
$employeeDetails = DB::table('employees')
                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'employees.user_id')
                            ->leftjoin('cost_centres', 'cost_centres.id', '=', 'employees.cost_centre_id')
                            ->leftjoin('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'employees.department_id')
                            ->leftjoin('sections', 'sections.id', '=', 'employees.section_id')
                            ->leftjoin('employee_positions', 'employee_positions.id', '=', 'employees.position_id')
                            ->leftjoin('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'employees.team_id')
                            ->leftjoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'employees.category_id')
                            ->leftjoin('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'employees.branch_id')
                            ->leftjoin('areas', 'areas.id', '=', 'employees.area_id')
                            ->leftjoin('employee_grades', 'employee_grades.id', '=', 'employees.grade_id')
                            ->leftjoin('attendance_group_area','attendance_group_area.area_id','employees.area_id')
                            ->whereIn('employees.id', $leaveTransactionEmployees)
                            ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')
                            ->select('employees.*','users.name as name', 'cost_centres.name as costCentre', 'departments.name as department', 'sections.name as section',
                                'employee_positions.name as position', 'teams.name as team', 'areas.name as area', 'employee_grades.name as grade',
                                'categories.name as category', 'attendance_group_area.attendance_group_id as attendance_group_id')
                            ->get();
        return response()->json($employeeDetails);
```

as you can see the only the filter I have right now is this and its only filter for 1 column

`->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')`

How can I use the same value to filter all the column in all the table I leftjoined if the value exist in any of my column.

Comment: You mean all fields in the `users` table?

Comment: sry should have be more specific, from all the table I join in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `orWhere`.

```
$collection->where('sth', '=', '%'.$xxxx.'%')
           ->orWhere('sth_other', '=', '%'.$xxxx.'%')
           ->orWhere(...)
           ...
           ->get();
```

Comment: i did something like this `->orWhere('users.name', 'Muhammad Izzat')
                            ->orWhere('cost_centres.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')
                            ->orWhere('departments.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')
                            ->orWhere('sections.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')
                            ->orWhere('employee_positions.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')
                            ->orWhere('teams.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')`

Comment: it provide me with data but it didnt filter anything

Comment: The answer depends on what was the first element in your query arguments chain - you need to group them so only the filters are where-orwhere-orwhere, but other elements of your query should stay as they were before.

Comment: For example - if your first `where()` was sth like this: `->where('1', '=', 1)` than it always would give you all the elements from given table. You need to understand, that your filters chain is separate from other query elements and it has to start with `where()` not `orWhere()`.

Comment: so i need to start with `where()` thanks it worked now

Answer (score 1):

You can `CONCAT()` the fields you want to search, and use `LIKE` to match on that concatenated result:

`->where('CONCAT( ' . join( ', " ", ', [ 'users.name', 'cost_centres.name', 'departments.name' ] ). ' )', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')`

This results in:

`->where(CONCAT( users.name, " ", cost_centres.name, " ", departments.name ), 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')`

You can also use MySQL's [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function to concatenate the columns, although it doesn't really shorten your code and I don't think it will affect performance noticeably:

`->where('CONCAT_WS( " ", ' . join( ', ', [ 'users.name', 'cost_centres.name', 'departments.name' ] ) . ' )', 'LIKE', '%'.$filterValue.'%')`

Of course, you'll want to change this array `[ 'users.name', 'cost_centres.name', 'departments.name' ]` to include all the columns you want to search in.

Note that depending on the value of `$filterValue` it may match on boundaries between concatenated columns. To avoid this, replace `" "` in the `join()` with some sentinel string that is unlikely to be present in the search string, e.g. `"###"`.

Comment: i receive this error when trying to concat `Call to undefined function App\\Helpers\\CONCAT()"`

Comment: @kmoser I believe you should use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)